# Compare performance range over the years for each unique school

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a dataset with Year, school_id, Performance range (let's call it P_range).

- Years range from 2019 - 2016
- Performance Range from 0-5
- Over 2000 unique school_ids

Basically I need to know how each school_id perfomed over the years within performance range.

Example:

| YEAR | School_ID | P_Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 4 |
| 2018 | 1 | 5 |
| 2017 | 1 | 3 |
| 2016 | 1 | 3 |
| 2019 | 2 | 1 |

I would like a fourth column that would look at the dataset and tell me in which year did its performance alter

- 2019-2018 this school **decreased** the range
- 2018-2017 this school **increased** the range
- 2017-2016 this school **maintained** the range
- 2016 would not compare to anything which is "First evaluation"

So at any given time, when we look at the results of 2019 we would see a sum of results being compared to 2018 and so on.
We need to know at a yearly rate, how many "maintained", "decreased" "increased" or "First evaluation"

If it were on excel this would be the formula:
=IF(B2=B3;IF(C2>C3;"INCREASED";IF(C2=C3;"MAINTANED";"DECREASED"));IF(B2<>B3;"1ST EVALUATION"))

Comment: Please don't: spam tags; put tags in titles; include text content as images; revert legitimate edits. Do take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Also please share your work in Tableau Public, with clear calculations, you can sample out the data